# Что означает %N после IP адреса, где N - какое-то число

Tags: ip

```
Локальный IPv6-адрес канала . . . : fe80::c0d5:8357:ef78:e14a%5(Основной)
```

Что такое в данном случае `%5`?  Я подозреваю, что это ID сетевого интерфейса, так ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Это ID интерфейса.
Если подряд идут IP v6, а за ним IP v6, например при вывод через IPconfig номер интерфейса указывается только для 1 из 2-х адресов, для второго это подразумевается атоматически